# Sed - adding tags to the beginning and end of a line while skipping empty lines

Tags: linux, sed

I have multiple text file that i'm trying to add paragraph tags

to the beginning and end of each line in the files, while skipping the 1st and empty lines.

So far i came up with the below code, but it's not skipping empty lines and its adding the

below on a new line.

```
for i in *.txt; do sed -i -e '1 ! s/.*/<p>&<\/p>/' $i; done
```

For example lets say the text file looks like this:

```
This Is the File Name

Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3

Paragraph 4
```

This is the output i'm getting with my code

```
This Is the File Name
<p>
</p>
<p>Paragraph 1
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>Paragraph 2
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>Paragraph 3
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
```

What i'm trying to get is this:

```
This Is the File Name

<p>Paragraph 1</p>

<p>Paragraph 2</p>

<p>Paragraph 3</p>

<p>Paragraph 4</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `.*` matches empty strings. Simply make it require at least one character with `..*`:

```
$ sed -i -e '1 ! s|..*|<p>&</p>|' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
This Is the File Name

<p>Paragraph 1</p>

<p>Paragraph 2</p>

<p>Paragraph 3</p>

<p>Paragraph 4</p>
```

Comment: the ..* works but for some reason the </p> still shows up on newline instead of the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
 awk '$1 !~ /^$/ {print "<p>" $0 "</p>"} $1 ~ /^$/ { print ""}' file
```